# Mongodb Full Text Search Control Score based on % of text matched

Tags: mongodb, solr, lucene, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas

I am using Atlas full text search in MongoDb (Hosted on Atlas):

I have following search index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "name": {
        "indexOptions": "docs",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "test": {
        "indexOptions": "docs",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By Default "lucene.standard" analyser is used.

I have following demo data in the same collection:

[image]

When I search using keyword using "clm chest" I get the following result:

[image]

**How can I get the second result on top, since in 2nd result % of text match is greater.**

( I understand currently the score is greater for the first one, because the word "clm" is matched on both indexed fields)
How can I get the scoring only on the best field match not the all search index field combined.

Comment: try adding boosting on the best field... "score": { "boost": { "value": 3 } }...you can refer more here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/scoring/

Comment: I have already tried that it give first one the score 5 and the 2nd one: 2, thus  doing the opposite.